# how to get Http status code of an initial URL using rest assured?

Tags: rest-assured

Suppose we have a URL http://example1.com and we have 301 URL redirect setup on this, that redirects to http://example2.com.

After reaching http://example2.com, it returns the code 200.

I am using following Rest assured code to get the HTTP status:

```
public int httpResponseCodeViaGet(String url) {
    System.out.println("Checking Status code for URL : "+ url);
    int code = RestAssured.get(url).statusCode();
    System.out.println("Status code is : "+ code);
    return code;
}
```

This is returning me 200 from URL http://example2.com, I want to check the redirect status for my initial URL http://example1.com

How to get Http status code of an initial URL using rest assured.

Thank you,
Jagjeet

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
@Test
public void followsRedirectsByDefault() throws Exception {
        given().
        param("url1", "/hello").
        expect().statusCode(302).
        when().
        get("url2");
}
```

I also suggest to refer official documentation of rest assured [tests](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/master/examples/rest-assured-itest-java/src/test/java/io/restassured/itest/java/RedirectITest.java) which contains similar cases with different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable following redirects:

```
given()
.config(RestAssured.config().redirect(redirectConfig().followRedirects(false)))
```

Here you can find more examples:
https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/ReleaseNotes15